# Android Placing Text (bar) at bottom of Application

Tags: android, menubar

I want to be able to display text (a bar if you will) at the bottom of my application dynamically to indicate if the the application is online or not (an endless issue for users currently). I don't need for this to have any action, but I do need it to be able to control it displaying or not based on them toggling between online and offline mode. So the split action bar is not what I am looking for.

Not enough reputation points to post an example. Doh. Here is the link:

[Ugly example, look at bottom](http://i61.tinypic.com/6jelp1.jpg)

Something simple is fine - I am good with XML based or dynamic (though I will also need to hide and show it dynamically).

Thanks!

Comment: Would a Toast do, or do you want the message to be completely persistent? Toasts automatically disappear.

Comment: "Not enough reputation points to post an example" -- if you mean a diagram or image, post it somewhere else and link to it from here. Beyond that, a crouton sounds like what you want: https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Comment: Toast won't do. I need it permanently there. Also I already have a Action Bar at the top but no room for displaying the mode - I want it to be very obvious. I'll check out the Crouton and add the image via a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic solution. Define your method that the activity will use to hide / display your bottom TextView (text bar?).

In your XML:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_bar"
     ...
     ...
     android:visibility="gone"/>
```

In your activity:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{
    private TextView mTextBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_xml);
        ...
        ...
        mTextBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_bar);
    }

    public void updateVisibility(boolean visible){
        int visibility = (visible) ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE;
        mTextBar.setVisibility(visibility);

    }
}
```

Initially, the TextView (your text bar) has it's visibiity set to gone. Dynamically, when you want to show it call the updateVisibility(true) method to show it, and updateVisibility(false) to hide it.

Since I'm not sure how you are handling the check for the network status (in queries, in the onCreate, etc). I don't know what you intended to do for the TextView. If you need advice on how to position the TextView on the bottom of the screen I can provide example code for that as well.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I have added an example (though ugly) above. I'll give this a try and see if it works. The online/offline is actually just a mode in the app that I handle. Actual connectivity is handled differently. The idea is to support someone who has no or intermittent connectivity, but allow them to work without delays of synch failing.

Comment: I'll vote you correct after I have tested it..but looks sound. :)

Comment: That makes sense to me, and the TextView can be exchanged with a LinearLayout or some sort of other View if your are wrapping a TextView in a parent layout or something to position it! Good luck, I hope it works!

Comment: Lucas. Thanks for the help! Partial success...Had to also do a RelativeLayout around the textview, The only problem is that when I hide the RelativeLayout, then bottombar pops to the top. I'll create a separate item for that though..

Comment: I figured you would need to wrap it in a layout, I'm assuming a RelativeLayout to center the textview within it, while the RelativeLayout is aligned to the bottom. The bottombar you are referring to is the RelativeLayout popping up to the top when you hide it?

Comment: Yes. So looks good until I hide the RelativeLayout with the TextView (Offline Mode) in it. Then the original tool bar at bottom pops up to the very top. Tried to set the bottom tool bar to android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  but then they lay on top of each other...

Comment: Here is a linking to the new issue with all the details... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224145/android-making-bottom-tool-bar-not-move-to-top-of-layout